# Encoding URL into ASCII using javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, ascii, encode

I am writing a php script-wrapper for my API encode/decode requests and responses. The php script works fine with forms but I can't send properly encoded requests using javascript (angular)

In details:

1. I have an encoded request (on client side):

> {"ct":"2UExUFiKFiZeT73AbLWYrCzJZnYUuCaaLq6VKcaboj/VQxDIrRXa6b4FvbVJXgU9","iv":"5c37e23d740ceb7611cb707bacd66633","s":"11bd03dda58ffbbe"}

2. The form converts this request into

> %7B"ct"%3A"2UExUFiKFiZeT73AbLWYrCzJZnYUuCaaLq6VKcaboj/VQxDIrRXa6b4FvbVJXgU9%3D%3D"%2C"iv"%3A"5c37e23d740ceb7611cb707bacd66633"%2C"s"%3A"11bd03dda58ffbbe"%7D

3. It works, but I need to replicate it using angular http.get()

http.get doesn't convert this request properly. I tried to use encodeURI() but it doesn't help, obtain:

> "%7B%22ct%22:%222UExUFiKFiZeT73AbLWYrCzJZnYUuCaaLq6VKcaboj/VQxDIrRXa6b4FvbVJXgU9%22,%22iv%22:%225c37e23d740ceb7611cb707bacd66633%22,%22s%22:%2211bd03dda58ffbbe%22%7D"

It converts quotes, what based on the previous example I don't need

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: The string from `encodeURI` will **not** include leading and trailing quotes. That's just an artifact of how you're looking at it. Proof: https://jsfiddle.net/9z896mon/

Comment: It replaces internal quotes, but the form doesn't do that as you can see in paragraph 2 and encodeURI (you can see it in your example) doesn't replace colons

Comment: In a form post (e.g., `multipart/form-data`), `"` and `%22` are identical. If you have a server process that treats them differently, you have a broken server process.

Comment: *That said*, if you need to undo that, it's trivial: `encodeURI(data).replace(/%22/g, '"')`

Comment: Added 

encodeURI(request).replace(/%22/g,'"').replace(/,/g,"%2C").replace(/:/g,"%3A");

and it seems to work

Many thanks